# 「行くときゃ誰とゆく」— what's this きゃ and the とs?

Tags: particle-と, contractions

I'm trying to understand the lyrics to the children's song 雨降りお月さん (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21JW-j5JJdc ; analysis here http://homepage3.nifty.com/funahashi/sonota/hoka23.html ).  What's up with these verses:

> 雨降りお月さん　　雲の[蔭]{かげ}
>   お嫁に行く**ときゃ**　誰**と**ゆく
>   ひとりで[傘]{からかさ}　　　さしてゆく
>   傘ない**ときゃ**　　　誰**と**ゆく

1. Is the きゃ a contraction, and if so, of what? What does it mean?
2. Are those とs companionship, conditional, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ときゃ is a contraction of [とき]{時}は
- 誰**と** is "**with** who"

Does this answer your questions?